# Discord.js v14 Pagination requiring deferReply() but it sends "Bot is thinking....." forever

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord.js v14 bot using Javascript and was trying to make embed pagination by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDfjMzEnSZQ). But in the tutorial they add "`i.deferReply();`" after the "`if condition`" in "`collector.on('collect')`", but when I am doing the same, it sends "Bot is thinking..." message that doesn't go away and the buttons in it also do not work.

If I remove the deferReply method and click a button in the embed, it takes some time then updates the embed but shows "This interaction failed" even though the embed was updated.

So, I tried and came up with this method of sending a blank message (zero width unicode character) :

```js
i.reply({
    content: '​'
}).then((m) => {
    m.delete();
});
```

This is my full code as of now :

```js
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ComponentType, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    async execute(interaction, pages, time = 60000) {
        await interaction.deferReply();

        if (pages.length == 1) {
            const page = interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [pages],
                components: [],
                fetchReply: true
            });

            return page;
        }

        const prev = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('prev')
            .setEmoji('◀️')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            .setDisabled(true)

        const home = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('home')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setDisabled(true)

        const next = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('next')
            .setEmoji('▶️')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)

        const buttonRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(prev, home, next)
        let index = 0;

        let currentPage = await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [pages[index]],
            components: [buttonRow],
            fetchReply: true
        });

        const collector = await currentPage.createMessageComponentCollector({
            componentType: ComponentType.Button,
            time
        });

        collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
            if (i.user.id != interaction.user.id) {
                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setDescription('You can\'t use these buttons!')

                return i.reply({
                    embeds: [embed],
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            }

            i.reply({
                content: '​'
            }).then((m) => {
                m.delete();
            });

            if (i.customId == 'prev') {
                if (index > 0) index--;
            } else if (i.customId == 'home') {
                index = 0;
            } else if (i.customId == 'next') {
                if (index < pages.length - 1) index++;
            }

            if (index == 0) prev.setDisabled(true);
            else prev.setDisabled(false);

            if (index == 0) home.setDisabled(true);
            else home.setDisabled(false);

            if (index == pages.length - 1) next.setDisabled(true);
            else next.setDisabled(false);

            await currentPage.edit({
                embeds: [pages[index]],
                components: [buttonRow]
            });

            collector.resetTimer();
        });

        collector.on('end', async (i) => {
            await currentPage.edit({
                embeds: [pages[index]],
                components: []
            });
        });
        return currentPage;
    }
}
```

Please help if any way of not sending a blank message is possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i.deferReply()` creates a new message with a "Bot is thinking ..." message, as it waits for a reply. Whereas not deferring it suggests shows the "failed" message. This is because your bot has not replied to this interaction, so Discord assumes that it broke and didn't respond before breaking.

Discord.JS will resolve the defer or interaction when you call one of the following in the interaction (your `i` variable):

- `reply()` - Does not work with deferred messages.
- `editReply()`
- `deferReply()`
- `fetchReply()`
- `deleteReply()`
- `followUp()`

So how can we solve it? We *could* send a message (thus resolving the message) and remove it again. You can remove your defer reply, and replace it like so:

```js
i.reply("We got your interaction!")
.then((msg) => { 
  setInterval(() => {
    msg.delete()
  }, 3000)
});
```

Let's break this down. It sends the message "We got your interaction", and once it has sent, it gets the message that it sent, waits 3 seconds (3000 ms) and deletes it again. It has resolved the defer, but has also removed the message to reduce clutter in your channel.

**Bonus Tip:** You can send the message only to the person who interacted by changing the `ephemeral` option to true, changing the `i.reply` like accordingly:

```js
i.reply({content: "We got your interaction", ephemeral: true})
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I can use the ephemeral option.